# Javascript:Define Long Int

Tags: javascript, range

I've read a lot about Data Types in javascript, but found nothing about long int.
I need to know how to define Long Int in javascript.
The reason is the input of following methods of Range object accepts Long data type as second parameter :

```
    var storedSelection = document.createRange();
    storedSelection.setStart(document.body,  );
    storedSelection.setEnd(document.body,  );
```

This Image is captured from WebStorm IDE, please pay attention to type  mentioned in this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've read a lot about JavaScript's data types as you say then you should already know that:

1. JS variables are loosely typed. That is, when you declare a variable you don't give it a type (only assigned values have a type).
2. Any given variable can be assigned values of different types at different times. That is, having set `x = 12` you can later set `x = "some string"` or `x = { some : "object" }` and so forth.
3. JS only has one number type, floating point numbers (IEEE-754 doubles), so generally speaking no distinction is made between integers and decimals.

I don't know where you read that the range methods accept a "long int data type" as a parameter, but for that parameter you can pass in a JS variable that you know holds an integer, or a numeric literal, or even a function call that returns a number:

```
function getNumber() {
   return 15;
}

var myVariable = 20;

var storedSelection = document.createRange();
storedSelection.setStart(document.body, 12);
storedSelection.setEnd(document.body, myVariable);
storedSelection.setEnd(document.body, getNumber() );
```

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals

P.S. If you have a non-integer value as a result of a calculation, say you're calculating your range by dividing the total length by three or something, you can force the result to be an integer by rounding to the nearest integer with [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) or rounding down with [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) or rounding up with [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil). See also the [`Math` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, nnnnnn. please take look at the I've just put that in Question. and guide me

Comment: Don't worry about what WebStorm is telling you there, it's getting a bit carried away. You just need to put an integer literal or variable as shown in my answer. Try it and see what happens.